# Image not fitting in grid view cell in windows phone 8

Tags: gridview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, gmgridviewcell

[image]i want to append the image url to image controller in grid view .
 but image is not properly fitted to grid view cell. so please any one help me to how to do this.

MY CODE:

```
<GridView x:Name="listviewfreecredits" Margin="0,-1,0.643,10" Height="521" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="listviewfreecredits_ItemClick"  >
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid  Margin="10,0,0,0"  >
                                    <Border  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,5,0,5">

                  [![enter image description here][1]][1]

                                        <Image Source="{Binding DealImage}" Stretch="None" Width="180" Height="245" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DealID}" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBlock>


                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                    </GridView>
```

codeview:

```
 JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(result);
                JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["Deals"];
                if (jarr != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string DealImage = (string)jarr[i]["DealImage"];

                        freecredit obj = new freecredit();
                        obj.DealImage = Url.imgurl + DealImage;

                        this.listviewfreecredits.Items.Add(obj);

                    }
                }
```

in the above screenshot  in girdview cell image is not properly fitted.(image was cutting).how to minimize image.please help me.

**EDIT:**

finally I got a solution.Just I  removed Strech=none"   and  replaced with Stretch="Uniform".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `Stretch="None"` or replace it with `Stretch="UniformToFill"` on the `Image` depending on how you want it cropped.

Comment: Thank you for your response.small correction Strech="Uniform" is  working for me.